# Detecting which of multiple Unique Keys was violated?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, constraints

I need to catch  `Unique` Constarints in my C# Winforms application. In my previous version I only had one `UniqueKey` which was `UK_StudentNo`so I catched the violation using  the code below with `SQLException` constraint number `2627` when the user tried to give the same student number for different students.

```
catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Number==2627)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Student number already given");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Database Error !");
                }
                throw;
            }
```

But now, I have another `UniqueKey` which is `UK_Student_NationalID`and I cannot differ these 2 `UniqueKeys` with their `ConstraintNumber` so I cannot understand which UniqueKey violation throws the exception. How can I make a difference between these 2 UniqueKeys when I want to show messages like `"Student number already given"` or `"NationalID already given"`

Comment: Check the `ex.Message`, it should say which constraint was violated.

Comment: @RBarryYoung `ex.Message.contains("UK_StudentNo")` really worked for me, thx

Comment: I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the exception's message in `ex.Message`, it should indicate which constraint was violated.

You may also be able to find additional information in the `ex.Errors` collection.